# Script task to download excel file from "Sharepoint Online" with Office365 Credentials

Tags: excel, ssis, sharepoint-online, script-task

I am a frequent SSIS user but not a frequent Script task user.

I am trying to download a bunch of excel files from SharePoint Online(https://company.sharepoint.com/xyz/file1.xlsx), I have a set of ***office 365 credentials*** that are to be used for access.

My plan is to download the xlsx files to a local location and then load the data to my SQL server db.

However I was not able to find a script task script that would help me go about this specific task(special emphasis on office 365 credentials).

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: SSIS has `Connection manager for HTTP Connections`. Did you try that? You'll need domain in additon to username, password. Also, go through : http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Downloading-a-file-over-HTTP-the-SSIS-way.aspx

Comment: When I try to create the HTTP connection, I get an error when I test the connection saying "Error 401, connection forbidden"

Comment: Correction: Error 403

Comment: I understand, that's because of restrictions on domain. You'll have to contact admin for correct setting and necessary bypass.

Comment: ok, so I figured this one out, the SharePoint Online uses Office365 Authentication, which is not the same as standard login. I had a script task and used SharePoint Online SDK and referenced dlls from the script task.